# List Class filled with pointers losing adresses on return

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a class called DiGraph, that contains an array to Node pointers:

```
DiGraph::DiGraph(int Size) : count(0){
    nodes = new Node *[Size];
}
```

Now I want to define the function getNodes() which is essentially supposed to return the array in list form:

```
Liste<Node*> DiGraph::getNodes() {
    Liste<Node*> nlist(count+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        nlist.append(nodes[i]);
    }
    return nlist;
}
```

At the end of the function the nlist is filled correctly but somehow the resulting copy at the function call does not contain the correct pointers but all other variables.

```
DiGraph a(6);
a.addNode(new Node("A", 50, 50));
Liste<Node*> gN = a.getNodes(); //gN does not contain the same pointers that were returned
```

The class 'Liste' is basically a dynamic array with templates and some fancy functions.

Now I think the answer is probably gonna be that nlist gets destroyed after the function ends but the pointers still remain valid in the nodes variable so why does the copy contain invalid ones?

**EDIT**

This is the list class:

```
#ifndef _LISTE_H
#define _LISTE_H

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
class Liste {
private:
    T *_values;
    int _last;
    int _size;

    bool isFull();
    int find(T value);
    void increase();
    void decrease();

public:
    Liste(int size = 8);
    Liste(Liste &list);
    ~Liste();
    void append(T value);
    void remove(T value);
    T getValueAt(int pos);
    int size();

    T operator[](int pos);
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
Liste<T>::Liste(int size) {
    _size = size;
    _last = 0;
    _values = new T[size];
}

template <typename T>
Liste<T>::Liste(Liste &list) {
    _size = list._size;
    _last = list._last;
    _values = list._values;
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
Liste<T>::~Liste() {
    delete[] _values;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void Liste<T>::increase() {
    T *tmp = new T[_size * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        tmp[i] = _values[i];

    delete[] _values;
    _values = tmp;
    _size *= 2;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void Liste<T>::decrease() {
    _size /= 2;
    T *tmp = new T[_size];

    for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        tmp[i] = _values[i];

    delete[] _values;
    _values = tmp;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
bool Liste<T>::isFull() {
    return _last == _size;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
int Liste<T>::find(T val) {
    int pos;

    for (pos = 0; pos < _last; pos++)
        if (_values[pos] == val)
            return pos;
    return -1;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
T Liste<T>::getValueAt(int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || pos >= _last)
        throw "OutOfBoundsException";

    return _values[pos];
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void Liste<T>::append(T val) {
    if (isFull())
        increase();

    _values[_last] = val;
    _last += 1;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
void Liste<T>::remove(T val) {
    int pos = find(val);

    if (pos == -1)
        throw "ValueNotFoundException";

    for (; pos < _last - 1; pos++)
        _values[pos] = _values[pos + 1];
    _last -= 1;

    if (_last < _size / 4)
        decrease();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
int Liste<T>::size() {
    return _last;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T>
T Liste<T>::operator[](int pos) {
    return getValueAt(pos);
}

#endif
```

Comment: You're returning a copy of `Liste<Node*>`. Did you provide an appropriate (deep) copy constructor?

Comment: does "some fancy functions" include a correct copy constructor?

Comment: `template <typename T>
Liste<T>::Liste(Liste &list) {
 _size = list._size;
 _last = list._last;
 _values = list._values;
}` Sould this suffice? Since it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
Liste<T>::Liste(Liste &list) {
    _size = list._size;
    _last = list._last;
    _values = list._values;
}
```

What this code does is make the new Liste object (constructed from the copy constructor) point to the memory address of an existing Liste object. But this object will be destroyed so you get a dangling pointer. You need to perform a hard copy of the values.

```
template <typename T>
Liste<T>::Liste(const Liste &list) { // <--- const
    _size = list._size;
    _last = list._last;
    _values = new T[_size];
    for( std::size_t iter = 0 ; iter < _size ; ++iter )
    {
        _values[iter] = list._values[iter];
    }
}
```

It is good modern practice to wrap pointer members to a smart pointer (eg `unique_ptr<>`). This way you will never forget to delete everything and object hold is guaranteed to be cleaned up even in a case of an incomplete constructor (exception thrown).

If you plan to return-by-value you should research into how to make your Liste class move-aware

Your `T operator[](int pos);` could also return a contained item by reference to allow immediate modification of the object ( `T& operator[](int pos);` ) cause, as it is, it returns a copy of the object that lies at `_values[pos]` and is most likely not what you want. Similarly for your `T getValueAt(int pos);` public method.

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it, the Liste class was provided by my professor, but I understand your last point it makes sense. I'm not using smart pointers or vectors just because the lecture didn't cover it yet. The const is just good practice right? Or are there other benefits than safety in this case?

Comment: @Siraja `const` is there so you won't modify the object by mistake. It will also allow you to catch temporary objects too (rvalues), which you can't do with a simple reference. I guess the point of the exercise was to find the problem in the copy constructor.